# Own back button for drilldown charts

Tags: highcharts

I have a pie chart with drilldown data.

Is it possible to hide the default back button and to trigger the back function from my own button?

Comment: can you provide what you have worked out till now?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's possible. Just create your own button and after click call `chart.drillUp()` function. See [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.drillUp).

**Highcharts v5 and v6:**
In Highcharts 5 classes were added to every element on a chart, so we can simply hide the button: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zzLuQ/87/

```
.highcharts-drillup-button {
  display: none;
}
```

**Highcharts v4:**

To disable default button, set text to empty string, see: http://jsfiddle.net/zzLuQ/

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        drillUpText: ''
    }
});
```

Comment: There is still a little box there, can we remove it completely?

Comment: Added solution for Highcharts v5 and v6