# Issue on Disabling (Not Displaying) Highcharts Drill-up Back Button

Tags: highcharts

I have my own custom btton to dril up highchart chart by using `chart.drillUp();` function but I still getting highchart built in drill up button so I tried to disable default button by setting it's text to empty string as:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        drillUpText: ''
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/u4ao5z6f/)

but still there is a small button in the chart in drill-down. Can you please let me know how to get rid of it completely?

Comment: How about displaying that button outside the visible chart? See [drillUpButton.position](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#drilldown.drillUpButton.position) option. Anyway, wouldn't be easier to remove drilldown.js module and adapt `point.events.click` callback to setup new data?

Comment: Hi Pawel, you are right one solution could be using the `.position` but I didnt get what you mean by using `point.events.click`? can you please let me know how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Simply in `point.events.click` set new data for the chart according to the clicked point. Then in drillup button, set parent data.  Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AMwtV/). Well, only thing changed is animation, so it's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

You're able to enable/disable the button dynamically:

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
chart.showDrillUpButton(); // enable
chart.drillUpButton = chart.drillUpButton.destroy(); // disable
```

Running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9buhzzbh/

In your case, you can put the disable line in the drillDown event function to disable it.

---

**Update** the css way to do this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23080111/1589218